# Software to emulate audio devices that can mux input and split output

Tags: audio, windows, usb

The problem I have is that I'm using Windows 7. and I need to be able to output audio from a PC to 2 devices simultaneously and have the inputs of both devices be valid recording devices.

However, I am using usb headsets (digital) so I can't use audio sound card channels.

I'm not sure but, if there some kind of software that can act as a virtual cable that can then output to multiple devices as well as receive from multiple inputs, that would be perfect.
Or anything that can manipulate audio streams really.

What Ive looked into so far that ***I*** couldn't get to work:

Audicity (couldn't manage to output to 2 devices)

Virtual Audio Cable

VB Audio Cable (can't really use this anyway because of the licensing)

VB ASIO Bridge

USB Y-splitters (couldn't find any)

---

Thanks

Comment: As it currently stands, it is not clear what you are asking.  What kind of devices are you trying to hook the PC up to?  What kind of inputs do they take?  Do the two feeds have to contain different audio or the same?  Do levels have to be different between them?  What outputs are available on your PC?  How many of each?  Is using an external audio interface an option?

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm trying to hook up 2 USB headsets with mics onto a PC. The 2 should get the same audio with the same levels. The PC can be assumed to have no other outputs at this time (but any way to add additional outputs is fine). External audio interface sounds interesting but I know nothing about those so I can't answer.

Comment: so you are trying to use them for recording and need both users to be able to hear what is already recorded?  Is that what you are trying to do?  You shouldn't have to do anything special, just configure the DAW to output on two interfaces and setup routing from the two interfaces assuming they are supported by the software.

Answer (score 1):

What about asio4all driver? That 'can' output to two digital sound cards simultaneously. You might have timing/latency issues but it's free and could work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found solution for this that works and it's free (open source). You can even hear the audio source from three different audio outputs.

My hardware setup:

- PC with Realtek Audio (Windows 10)
- Two LG Displays connected with HDMI

What I wanted is that the audio will come out from both displays. Unfortunately Windows 10/Realtek Stereo Mix "repeater" only works with PC audio output or with the PC speaker not with two different HDMI Displays.

Steps:

1. Install this software: https://sourceforge.net/projects/virtualaudiopip/

- I had to reboot on mode that allows to install unsigned drivers: https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-unsigned-drivers-windows10/
- Run setup
- Go to folder: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Virtual Audio Pipeline" and right click on vrtaupipe.inf and select install (it will warn about unsigned driver)
- Install and copy msvcr100.dll to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Virtual Audio Pipeline"
- Reboot

2. Set Realtek Audio as default playback source
3. Enable Stereo Mix: https://windowsreport.com/play-sound-2-devices-windows-10/

- Select first TV display

4. Run C:\Program Files (x86)\Virtual Audio Pipeline\Audio_Repeater.exe

- Select Stereo Mix as the source
- Select second TV display as the output and press start

Audio should now hear from both TV displays and also from the PC speaker/output.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to setup a simple recording setup where each headset acts as a mic and the recording can be monitored by wearing the headset.  As long as your DAW software can support recording from the inputs, it should be possible to simply configure the output to go to both audio outputs (each headset shows up as it's own interface to the computer).

The more professional way that this is generally done is to have a professional audio interface that supports two inputs and an output.  You can use a headphone distribution amplifier to send the feed to both people's headphones and you can then mic them with a suitable professional quality microphone instead of a cheap, consumer quality USB headset mic which is really designed for lo-fi audio for chatting rather than being designed for recording.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you right, you want to be able to reroute your multiple inputs into 1 DAW and then send them out into various outputs.

I reckon you can but you may need more than 1 DAW open to do this.

http://jackaudio.org/

Jack allows you to do the virtual rerouting within your computer, but I'm not sure if it can  run the inputs of an interface dry. You can definitely take it out from a DAW or another audio player and send it into the DAW of your choice.

With all that routing though, you're bound to run into many latency issues. Why not just rent or borrow a multichannel interface if you don't want to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

OH MAN this was so hard to find an answer to... I was finally able to do it with Virtual Audio cable.  My understanding is that you have a program that is playing audio, and you want that audio to simultaneously be played out two USB audio devices.

Install Virtual Audio Cable - it comes with one virtual cable by default.  You may want to open the control panel (as Administrator) and enable Volume Control for convenience, but the other default settings seem fine.

Play your audio to this device; you can do it by setting it as the default in your Windows sound settings.

Then run the program called "Audio Repeater (KS)," which comes with Virtual Audio Cable.  This will simply copy audio from an input to an output - select the Virtual Audio Cable as the input, and your first USB sound device as the output, then hit start.

Run a second instance of Audio Repeater, this time selecting your second USB sound device.

If the audio devices are out of sync, you can change the buffer size in the Audio Repeater to adjust accordingly.